# split string into array of n words per index

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string

I have a string that I'd like to split in an array that has (for example) 3 words per index.
What I'd also like it to do is if it encounters a new line character in that string that it will "skip" the 3 words limit and put that in a new index and start adding words in that new index until it reaches 3 again. example

```
var text = "this is some text that I'm typing here \n yes I really am"

var array = text.split(magic)

array == ["this is some", "text that I'm", "typing here", "yes I really", "am"]
```

I've tried looking into regular expressions, but so far I can't really make sense of the syntax that is used in regex.

I have written a way to complicated function that splits my string into lines of 3 by first splitting it into an array of separate words using `.split(" ");` and then using a loop to add add it per 3 into another array. But with that I can't take the new line character into account.

Comment: You can't split with that magic. Loop over the string, count the spaces, `push` every 3rd space, and `\n` and there you go. Custom split

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try with this pattern:

```
var result = text.match(/\b[\w']+(?:[^\w\n]+[\w']+){0,2}\b/g);
```

since the quantifier `{0,2}` is greedy by default, it will take a value less than 2 *(N-1)* only if a newline is found *(since newlines are not allowed here: `[^\w\n]+`)* or if you are a the end of the string.

Comment: this is very close. the only problem I'm encountering with this is that it has trouble with special characters like `? # ! @ &`.Sometimes it simply strips those out of the string. I'm guessing this is related to `\w` since this only includes [a-zA-Z0-9_]?

Answer (score 3):

If you're interested in a regexp solution, it goes like this:

```
   text.match(/(\S+ \S+ \S+)|(\S+ \S+)(?= *\n|$)|\S+/g)
   // result ["this is some", "text that I'm", "typing here", "yes I really", "am"]
```

Explanation: match either three space separated words, or two words followed by spaces + newline, or just one word (a "word" being simply a sequence of non-spaces).

For any number of words, try this:

```
text.match(/((\S+ ){N-1}\S+)|(\S+( \S+)*)(?= *\n|$)|\S+/g)
```

(replace `N-1` with a number).

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
words = "this is some text that I'm typing here \n yes I really am".split(" ");
result = [];
temp = "";

for (i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
  if ((i + 1) % 3 == 0) {
    result.push(temp + words[i] + " ");
    temp = "";
  } else if (i == words.length - 1) {
    result.push(temp + words[i]);
  } else {
    temp += words[i] + " ";
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

Basically what this does is splits the string by words, then loops through each word. Every third word it gets to, it adds that along with what is stored in `temp` into the array, otherwise it adds the word to `temp`.

Comment: Please explain your answers

Answer (score 0):

Only if you know there are no words 'left', so the number of words is always a multiple of 3:

```
"this is some text that I'm typing here \n yes I really am".match(/\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+/g)
=> ["this is some", "text that I'm", "typing here \n yes", "I really am"]
```

but if you add a word:

```
"this is some text that I'm typing here \n yes I really am FOO".match(/\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+/g)
```

the result will be exactly the same, so "FOO" is missing.

Answer (score 0):

here one more way:
use this pattern `((?:(?:\S+\s){3})|(?:.+)(?=\n|$))`
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/aH7oB4)